# call mysql stored procedure in php

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to call mysql prepare statement and stuck in php error.

" Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\learn\mysqlsp.php on line 7 "

code:

```
include 'connect_db.php';

$dbclass=new db_connector();
$dbh=$dbclass->getDBH();

$stmt=$dbh->prepare("CALL callavg('city','population'");
$stmt->execute();
```

$dbh is a valid mysql resource link. I had define a DB connector class so that scope issue for $dbh get resolved but I am still not able to correct this error.

Kindly help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> $dbh is a valid mysql resource link

Then it is not a PDO object, and you cannot call the [prepare()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) method on it!

Either use `mysql_query()` with a MySQL resource, or use [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php), and `prepare()`.

Comment: @Benjamin Morel :) my bad. replace prepare() with mysql_query() doesn't resolve my concern. Can you please let me know can we use mysql_query() to run preparedstaements. Ex: mysql_query("CALL callavg('city','population'");

Comment: Prepared statements and stored procedures are not the same. [Prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) are used to precompile a query and bind it parameters later. To `CALL()` your stored procedure, just issue a `mysql_query('CALL callavg("city","population")', $dbh);`

Comment: Let me frame it correct, I have a stored proce in mysql [calavg] and I am trying to call directly from PHP via mysql_query() but mysql_query return false.

Comment: calling stored procedures using the older mysql extension only works if you have the latest version - i think it's 5.3.6 however, you can call a stored procedure with older versions of php by using the mysqli extension.

Comment: Just learned something, *f00*! And yes, [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) works as well as PDO for prepared statements if don't plan to use another database vendor.

Comment: @Benjamin Morel Awesome !!! It returned expected output .  Thanks Benjamin for spending your time to help me resolve this.